# Postgres json data filtering query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to sql and trying to get this postgres sql query working where I need to filter on the ports that are in a nested json array. Here is my json data set.

> [
> {
> "version":"1.3",
> "configuration":{
> "ipPerms":[
> {
> "Port":1234,
> "fromPort":0
> }
> ]
> }
> },
> {
> "version":"1.3",
> "configuration":{
> "ipPerms":[
> {
> "Port":5467,
> "fromPort":0
> },
> {
> "Port":143,
> "fromPort":0
> }
> ]
> }
> }
> ]

Main table has two columns id INT and data jsonb.

Here is what I tried.

> SELECT
> id,
> jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'configuration' -> 'ipPerms') -> 'Port' as to_port
> from
> groups
> where
> jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'configuration' -> 'ipPerms') -> 'Port' IN (
> SELECT
> p.port
> FROM
> databases d
> JOIN ports p ON d.id = p.database_id
> )

I get this error:

> set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE

I have seen posts where people recommending sub queries in WHERE clause but I don't really get how we can achieve this when the column itself needs to transformed using a fucntion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a subquery like the following, main table can be filtered based on nested JSON array elements.

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'configuration' -> 'ipPerms') ->> 'Port' AS to_port
    FROM groups
) AS subquery
WHERE to_port IN (
    SELECT p.port
    FROM databases d
    JOIN ports p ON d.id = p.database_id
);
```

Hope it works :)